# Event Bus in Fragment

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I have created one Activity (*DemoActivity.java*) with 2 Fragments (*FragmentOne.java*  and *FragmentTwo.java*).

I registered the `EventBus` in the Activity like this`EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

and created one Suscriber method in the Activity:

```
@Subscriber
public void abc(String str) {
    Log.i(TAG,"MainActivity Called !!");
}
```

Then I post an event from FragmentTwo.java on button click `EventBus.getDefault().post("");`

This scenario works fine for me. But when I create the same subscriber method in FragmentOne.java it is not working. Why?

Comment: You need to register the FragmentOne in EventBus like as same you are registering in activity

Comment: have you registered your fragment as event receiver?

Comment: @avi   i alreay tried like - EventBus.getDefault().register(getActivity());

Comment: Why get Activity you need to pass the reference of fragment where you have define Subscriber method. Attach you code for better reference here.

Comment: yes Vlad Matvienko. i used  @Subscriber annotation for that.. is it right? or there will be another workaround for that?

Comment: @Avi  got it.. i just passed 'this' instead of getActvity() and its works. thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your question there might be two things that are causing the issue:

1. You might have not registered the `EventBus` in your `FragmentOne` class like you did for your `DemoActivity` class.
2. If you have registered the  `EventBus` in the `FragmentOne` class then please check if `FragmentOne` fragment class is alive and in state to receive the event while posting the event from `FragmentTwo` class.

Edit

As seen from comments you have registered your `EventBus` as `EventBus.getDefault().register(getActivity())` due to this only your Activity will get registered. To register your `Fragment` use `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` in your `Fragment.onCreate()` method.

Comment: yup just did it.. but when i will unregister that fragments eventbus ?

Comment: `onDestroy()` method of `Fragment`

Answer (score 9):

Use [Sticky Events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) for fragment. Because fragments are loaded multiple offsets some time.

> Register and unregister your Eventbus:

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Register ");
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "Unregister");
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

> OnChildChange.class post event with `.postSticky()`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new OnChildChange(position));
```

> Subscribe EventBus with `sticky = true`:

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onCategoryChangeEvent(OnChildChange event){
    // get the event and remove drom sticky
    OnChildChange stickyEvent = EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(OnChildChange.class);

    if(stickyEvent != null) {
        // apply your logic or call methods 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Register EventBus at OnStart() in fragment.

```
  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}
```